# Passing Date to WCF REST Service via Kendo UI (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, jquery, kendo-grid

The idea
is i have calendar control from where i can select different dates. Based upon the dates selected i make a ajax call to WCF service (GetDealData()) to fetch some sets of data. 
Could you anyone please see whats wrong here? For two days i am going a bit crazy trying to figure out why does my GetRemoteData() method passes the same date (which is 25-10-2012) everytime i execute the OnDateChange Method even if i select different dates on my calendar control. Is it something to do with json data not being assigned properly?

```
$('#calendarContainer').kendoCalendar({
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        culture: "en-GB",
        change: onDateChange
});

function onDateChange() {
        var date = kendo.toString(this.value(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var bob = GetRemoteData(date);
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(bob);
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();          
    }
```

function GetRemoteData(date) {

```
        var chosenDate;

        if (typeof date=="undefined")
        {
            alert("it is null " + date);
            chosenDate = "25-10-2012";
        }
        else {
            alert("it is not null " + date);               
            chosenDate = date;
        }

        source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
         //   autoSync:true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/GetDealData",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        startDate:chosenDate
                    }
                }

            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        DealNumber: { type: "string" },
                        DealIssuer: { type: "string" },
                        Ticker: { type: "string" },
                        DealType: { type: "string" },
                        DealValue: { type: "number" },
                        DealStatus: { type: "string" },
                        DealPricingCompletionDate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 16
        });
        return source;
    }





    WCF Methods
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
      UriTemplate = "GetDealData?startDate={startDate}")]
    List<DealData> GetDealData(string startDate);


    public List<DealData> GetDealData(string startDate)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");                                 
        List<DealData> model =                      Service.GetDealData(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate,culture));         
        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems that this issue does not related to wcf - its just a JavaScript issue.
It seems, that your date is always undefined.

I'd try to find out what is the value of `this.value()`, and after this - `kendo.toString(this.value(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')` value.

For me its sound like some format issue may be.

You can use browser's console to debug JavaScript

Comment: Hi evgenyl! Thank you for your response. Yes the this.value() displays exact value from what i select in the calendar control. This is confirmed from the alert statements to see what the value actually is.The problem is in the transport section where i am specifying the data attribute. For some wierd reason it always assigns "25-10-2012" as a value to be sent to WCF Rest service even if the date variable has got some other value.

Comment: did you debug it? what is the value of chosenDate after if(typeof date== ...)? Also, I'd try to change string date repsresentation by Date()

Comment: Yes i get the actual value selected when debugging it after  if(typeof date== ...)? ... that means the variable "chosenDate" automatically gets the selected value passed in from "date" variable.its just that when i call the read method it passes null. I cannot change it into Date object as the WCF server expects the date  with string parameter. I am trying my best to send it as a string date for the time being.

Comment: Or it could be with the way i am checking the date value or the way i am assigning the value to chosenDate

Comment: Try to modify "null" value to something like Date.now() - this will give you 2 different dates for 2 requests

Comment: I got it working to send some string values but like before it sends the same value (assigned at the first instance) again and again . I just feel that its caching the parameter value under the hood. would love see a way to find out if we can tell ajax requests not to cache any parameter values

Comment: Thank you for your time evgenyl. Something else in the grid intialising process was causing the problem which was completely overlooked. Its been solved in the following thread. Keep up the good work evgenyl